# Mockito define behavior of mock when it is type cast

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

In Mockito, is it possible to define the behavior of a mock object in the event that it is type cast, perhaps as one can use Mockito's "when ... thenReturn" functionality to define the behavior of a mock object in the event that of its methods is called?

For example, in the following example class and test...

```
public class MyClass {
  public String myMethod(ObjectString arg) {
    ans = (String) arg;
    return ans;
  } 
}

public class MyClassTest {
  @Test
  public void myMethod_should_convert_to_string() {
    MyClass testMyClass = new MyClass();
    ObjectString mockObjectString = Mockito.mock(ObjectString.class);
    String expected = "expected string returned";
    Mockito.when(mockObjectString.IS_CAST_TO_STRING).thenReturn(expected);
    String actual = testMyClass.myMethod(mockObjectString);
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }
}
```

...is there something I can perhaps replace 'IS_CAST_TO_STRING' with that will cause mockObjectString to be cast to the specific value "expected string returned"?

Comment: no.... that would violate basic semantics of the java language. It's like asking if you can mock `1+1` to be `0`

Comment: Nothing in Java will let you change what happens when a cast occurs; not Mockito, not anything.

Comment: SuperPowerMock will let you... jk

Comment: Wait, are you actually trying to replace `toString()`, like to verify that `String x = myObj + " foo";` works? This could *look* like it's getting cast to a string, but `toString()` is actually getting called. Mocking that is just `Mockito.doReturn("expected").when(mock).toString();`

Comment: The other thing you could be asking is if you cast a Child to a Parent, how can you verify that the Parent's method is called. And you can't; that's not how OO works in Java. You also can't test dynamic dispatch this way because Java method calls are statically "linked."

Comment: Can you please provide some context? What are you trying to achieve? I can see some design smell here.

Answer (score 1):

An instance of `ObjectString` can never be cast to `String`. `String` does not inherit from any class called `ObjectString` nor does it implement any interface called `ObjectString`. Casting to `String` will **always** throw a `ClassCastException` unless `arg` is `null`.

On the other hand, if your class under test looked like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public String myMethod(final Object arg) {
        final String ans = (String) arg;
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Then, you could achieve what you're looking for *without* Mockito:

```
@Test
public void myMethod_should_convert_to_string() {
    MyClass testMyClass = new MyClass();
    String expected = "expected string returned";
    String actual = testMyClass.myMethod(expected);
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```